# Remove gamecenter record after app unintsall

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

How can I show dialog "Remove %AppName% from Game Center?" "You will no longer be listed on leaderboards for %AppName%" after game uninstall? Like that http://d74bwl3dcueqd.cloudfront.net/images/guide/8aee506afc014a77bfec06b81378d338/440x380_ac.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message is automatically shown by iOS when uninstalling an app that uses Game Center for achievements, leader boards, etc

Comment: That could be. I would not be surprised if that is the case.